# Accordion stops working when link is wraped inside

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I'm using accordion to toggle display onclick. It works fine If I use a simple text. Now I want to incorporate a link inside it. So my original code is this.

```
<div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#@item.Id.ToString()">
              <div class="data-table">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <p class="ptitle">Document Package @item.Id.ToString()<br /><span class="psubtitle">Date Created: @item.CreatedAt.ToString()</span><br /><span class="psubtitle">Date Updated: @item.UpdatedAt.ToString()</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right accordion-downarrow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></div>
                <div class="pull-right text-center"><p>PP<br /><span class="label label-warning">&nbsp;</span></p></div>
                <div class="pull-right text-center"><p>AMG<br /><span class="label label-danger">&nbsp;</span></p></div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
```

I want to change this line:

```
<p class="ptitle">Document Package @item.Id.ToString()<br /><span class="psubtitle">Date Created: @item.CreatedAt.ToString()</span><br /><span class="psubtitle">Date Updated: @item.UpdatedAt.ToString()</span></p>
```

Into something like this.

```
<p class="ptitle">@Html.ActionLink("Document Package " + item.Id.ToString(), "show", "documentpackage", new { id = item.Id }, null)<br /><span class="psubtitle">Date Created: @item.CreatedAt.ToString()</span><br /><span class="psubtitle">Date Updated: @item.UpdatedAt.ToString()</span></p>
```

When I change it to a link. The functionality of the accordion stops but the link works. I want to make the link work and at the same time retain the functionality of the accordion toggle. Any ideas? THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what the rendered HTML looks like?
Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what you're rendered HTML looks like, maybe you'll find a solution there.